# Dynamic type instantiation without locking dll

Tags: c#, dll, com+

I have a **COM+ Application** composed of several serviced components.

One of them instantiates on demand a type from a dll through  `Activator.CreateInstance(pluginType, args);`. The type is not a serviced component itself, it contains just the implementation of certain interface that the component knows about.

I don't have problems with the instantiation itself, the problem is that the dll is getting locked by the `dllhost.exe`, and I would like, if possible, to be able to replace it without shutting down the COM+ Application.

Is it possible somehow to unlock the dll without shutting down the COM+ App?

Or from another point of view, is there a way I could programmatically unload the dll to unlock it?

*NOTE:* The dll is located in the COM+ application root directory with rest of the dlls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loaded modules are referenced counted in windows.  In windows we have loadLibrary and freelibrary.  If freelibrary is called and the reference count is zero then the dll will be unloaded and free to replace, delete, etc.

In .NET though once an assembly is loaded into an appDomain it is there until the appdomain dies (unless reflection emit collectable assembly).  If you were to spawn another appdomain and do the create instance here when the new appdomain dies the assembly will be unloaded.

Asp.net does something called shadow caching.  Asp.net you can replace the dlls at anytime without having to kill the worker process.  They do this by not loading the dlls in the bin folder but instead they copy them to a seperate location and load them from there in a seperate appdomain.  They watch the bin folder, when a change happens they kill the appdomain, copy the dlls to the temp folder, and create a new appdomain.

Shadow Copying Assemblies
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279.aspx

Comment: Interesting. I'm wondering If can create a new `AppDomain` on the fly, enable shadow copying for it, load the dll into, and then instantiate the type. I'll test if this works.

Comment: It might mean a lot of changes to your app.  Here is a quick example I found on the internet http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29961/Shadow-Copying-of-Applications

Comment: I spent much more time than expected for this but, after fighting a lot against dynamic assembly loading issues, I have our simple plugin architecture running within our main COM+ Application. Thanks, you gave me clue.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a specific problem for COM+, it is universal on Windows and fundamental to the way it works.  Loading code from an executable file (exe or dll) is done by Windows creating a memory-mapped file for the executable file.  Code is only read from the file when a page fault requires actually reading the file and mapping the code into RAM.  This will happen repeatedly when other processes compete for RAM and the code gets unmapped.

The MMF puts a lock on the file.  Required so that the file cannot be modified while it has code mapped into RAM.

There's no workaround for this, the process that has the DLL loaded *must* terminate or must cooperate and unload the DLL before the lock is released.  At best you can rename the file while it is in use, that doesn't otherwise affect the process.

Comment: OK. I know it will be a matter for a different question, but what is the people using in the real world for creating a lose-coupled "plugin-like" architecture? I just need to be able to replace that small piece of code. An alternative would be leaving the entire implementation class in DB or even in text file and compile the code on the fly, but I don't see both approaches much appropriate.